# Is it possible to connect a USB stick to Samsung Galaxy S2 Phone?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2

I have a Samsung Galaxy S2 phone. It comes with a micro USB port which can be used for charging or connecting to a PC.

I am just wondering if the micro USB port can also be used to connect a USB memory stick. Is there something like a USB stick with a micro SD connection?

Perhaps the easier option is to use the existing cable. Can a USB Stick be connected to the phone in the same way the phone is connected to a PC using the existing cable?

Comment: I think you mean "microUSB" - "micro SD" is a type of SD card, completely unrelated to USB: http://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1214&bih=574&q=micro+sd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, you can** plug a USB stick to your Samsung Galaxy S2, provided that you have an Samsung Micro USB to USB Adapter.

For better results, connect your USB stick to the adapter, before connecting it to your phone.

See the official [Samsung Galaxy SII accessories](http://www.samsung.com/global/microsite/galaxys2/html/accessories.html) for further information.

[image: Samsung Micro USB to USB Adapter]

**Note:**
Usually within the phone box, Samsung sends a micro USB to USB cable.

---

The Samsung Micro USB to USB Adapter can also be found at [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005LGUCYM):

[image: Samsung Micro USB to USB Adapter]

<sup>Different in aspect from the one on the website.</sup>

Comment: Thanks @Zuul. I don't think I got it in the phone box so off to a tech shop. Each country may be different. I am based in Australia. (We tend to get things last!)